# Keep number of an ol with overflow

Tags: html, css, html-lists

If I use `overflow:hidden` in an ordered list the numbers disappear, how can I keep them and at the same time hide overflowing characters?

```css
li {
  overflow:hidden;
  max-width:70ch
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>Suspendisse venenatis arcu vitae tempor feugiat.</li>
  <li>Aenean pellentesque orci eu ligula venenatis sodales.</li>
  <li>Praesent sed quam et turpis accumsan luctus.</li>
  <li>Nullam sodales nisl eu ultricies convallis</li>
<ol>
```

Comment: Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshnayak/u7ydetb0/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`list-style-position: inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) on the list, this will place the numbers inside the list item:

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 70ch
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
  <li>Suspendisse venenatis arcu vitae tempor feugiat.</li>
  <li>Aenean pellentesque orci eu ligula venenatis.</li>
  <li>Praesent sed quam et turpis accumsan luctus.</li>
  <li>Nullam sodales nisl eu ultricies convallis</li>
</ol>
```

An alternate solution is to roll your own CSS and use CSS counters to auto-number items:

```css
/* counter */
ol {
  counter-reset: foo 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  counter-increment: foo 1;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(foo) ".";
}
/* position */
li {
  padding-left: 2em;
}
li::before {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2em;
  width: 1.75em;
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 70ch;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
  <li>Suspendisse venenatis arcu vitae tempor feugiat.</li>
  <li>Aenean pellentesque orci eu ligula venenatis.</li>
  <li>Praesent sed quam et turpis accumsan luctus.</li>
  <li>Nullam sodales nisl eu ultricies convallis.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
  <li>Suspendisse venenatis arcu vitae tempor feugiat.</li>
  <li>Aenean pellentesque orci eu ligula venenatis.</li>
  <li>Praesent sed quam et turpis accumsan luctus.</li>
  <li>Nullam sodales nisl eu ultricies convallis. Nullam sodales nisl eu ultricies convallis.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will behave slightly differently to a normal list. Multiline text will wrap _under_ the numbers, rather than remaining to the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! But how should I act if I have multi-line comments and still want to have the numbers placed before the first letter?

Comment: Oh... you could create a custom list where you position `::before` elements. I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom counter and consider `display:flex` to kee the indentation on wrap:

```css
li {
  overflow:hidden;
  max-width:70ch;
  display:flex;
}
ol {
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset:num;
}
ol li:before {
  content:counter(num) ". ";
  counter-increment:num 1;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <br>adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>Suspendisse venenatis arcu vitae <br>tempor feugiat.</li>
  <li>Aenean pellentesque orci eu ligula venenatis sodales.</li>
  <li>Praesent sed quam et turpis accumsan luctus.</li>
  <li>Nullam sodales nisl eu ultricies convallis</li>
<ol>
```